# Slackbot that supports parameters wrapped with quotation marks

Tags: go, slack, slack-api

I am trying to write a slackbot. I've tried a variety of frameworks from github, but the most promising I've used seems to be [hanu](https://github.com/sbstjn/hanu)

What I'd like to do is send a message to a bot like so:

```
@bot <command> "Something" "Another thing that contains spaces" "A final thing with spaces"
```

I'd like to then have each of those 3 parameters be passed as strings to a var, which then has a handle func which can be executed.

I just don't seem to be able to do this! The hanu framework linked above seems to use [this](https://github.com/sbstjn/allot) framework which states:

> The allot library supports placeholders and regular expressions for
>   parameter matching and parsing.

But because I'm a terrible developer, I can't seem to figure out how to do this in the framework above because there's no examples.

So I'd like to either be able to:

- figure out how to use the above library with those kind of parameters so I can start building something
- write a bot command that takes those kind of params myself using github.com/nlopes/slack and pass my own handler functions.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to abuse [`strings.FieldsFunc(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc) to split the string on whitespace only if it is not in a quoted section:

```
func main() {
  s := `@bot <command> "Something" "Another thing that contains spaces, it's great" "A final thing with spaces"`

  tokens := splitWithQuotes(s)
  for i, t := range tokens {
    fmt.Printf("OK: tokens[%d] = %s\n", i, t)
  }
  // OK: tokens[0] = @bot
  // OK: tokens[1] = <command>
  // OK: tokens[2] = "Something"
  // OK: tokens[3] = "Another thing that contains spaces, it's great"
  // OK: tokens[4] = "A final thing with spaces"
}

func splitWithQuotes(s string) []string {
  inquote := false
  return strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(c rune) bool {
    switch {
    case c == '"':
      inquote = !inquote
      return false
    case inquote:
      return false
    default:
      return unicode.IsSpace(c)
    }
  })
}
```

Strictly speaking, this approach might not work with all versions of golang since, per the documentation:

> If f does not return consistent results for a given c, FieldsFunc may crash.

...and this function definitely returns varying results for whitespace characters; however, it seems to work with go 1.9 and newer, so I guess it depends on your appetite for adventure!

Comment: that seems interesting. Can you show me how that might look with the example slack.Command("shout <word>", func(conv hanu.ConversationInterface) {
  str, _ := conv.String("word")
  conv.Reply(strings.ToUpper(str))
 })